# SWIFT 2 : Core Data does not seem to work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mobile

I am following a outstanding course on Swift but seems to be outdated when it comes to Core Data. I want to store a username and a password in core data but it does not seem to store anything permanent. Why?

Most tutorial on the net are outdated.

- I clicked the core data option when I created the empty proyect and created the needed Entity and attributes .

  ```
  let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

          let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
  ```

  let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context)

  ```
          newUser.setValue("Rober", forKey: "username")

          newUser.setValue("pass", forKey: "password")





          let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

          request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

          //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "kirsten")

      var results: [AnyObject]?
          do {
              results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
          } catch _ {
              results = nil
          }

          if results!.count > 0 {

              for result: AnyObject in results! {

                  if let username: String = result.valueForKey("username") as? String {

                      print(username)

                      result.setValue("kirsten", forKey: "username")

                      context.deleteObject(result as! NSManagedObject)

                      do {
                          try context.save()
                      } catch _ {
                      }

                  }

              }


          } else {

              print("No results")

          }
  ```

What can it be ? may there be any updated tutorial on handling core data in swift 2?
Thanks

----------------------------- SOLUTION : Core Data code that works well on Swift 2 -------------------
This bunch of code stores data and the displays it, if you want also to delete data just uncomment the line //    context.deleteObject(result as! NSManagedObject)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!


    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context)



    newUser.setValue("Roberto", forKey: "username")

    newUser.setValue("pass", forKey: "password")





    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

   //     request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = %@", "kirsten")

    var results: [AnyObject]?
    do {
        results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
    } catch _ {
        results = nil
    }

    if results!.count > 0 {

        for result: AnyObject in results! {

            if let username: String = result.valueForKey("username") as? String {

                print(username)


              //  result.setValue("Angel", forKey: "username")

            //    context.deleteObject(result as! NSManagedObject)

                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch _ {
                }

            }

            if let password: String = result.valueForKey("password") as? String {

                print(password)


                //  result.setValue("Angel", forKey: "username")

                //    context.deleteObject(result as! NSManagedObject)

                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch _ {
                }

            }

        }


    } else {

        print("No results")

    }



}
```

Comment: Can you post the part of `AppDelegate` where the `managedObjectContext` is declared and initialized?

Comment: Your code seems to be inserting a new `Users` object, then fetching all `Users` objects and deleting them.   So when you save the context, nothing will be written to the store.  Try deleting `context.deleteObject(result as! NSManagedObject)` to see if things are then saved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code snip which

> **save user details in Core Data using Swift 2.0**

```
//  Created by Ramdhan on 06/11/15.

import UIKit
import CoreData

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

    let managedObjectContext =
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var rePassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cell: UITextField!

    // MARK: - Controller life cycle stack

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    //MARK: Store user info on Device DB

    func saveUserInfoOnDB()
    {

        let entityObj =
        NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User",
            inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
        let userObj = User(entity: entityObj!,
            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        userObj.username = name.text
        userObj.password = password.text
        userObj.email_cell = cell.text

        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges
        {
            do
            {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
                let error: NSError? = nil

                if let err = error
                {
                    print("%@",err.localizedFailureReason)
                    print("Could not saved \(error), \(err.userInfo)")

                } else {
                    name.text = ""
                    password.text = ""
                    cell.text = ""
                    print("User info Saved")

                    performSegueWithIdentifier("loadManageAccountSegue", sender: nil)
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Entity snap shot

[image]